# Can UpdateByQuery be used to perform bulk update in elastic search.?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-dsl-py

I have a list of sequences e.g `1350, 1351, 1352, 1353, 1354, 1355, 1356, 1357, 1358, 1359, 1390` and a single `sensor_pk` and `record_type`. All the sequences documents share a common `sensor_pk` and `record_type`. I want to change the `sensor_pk` once instead of going through all the sequences and doing it individually. Here's what I have in python `elasticsearch_dsl`

```
    ubq = UpdateByQuery(using=es.es, index=es.ALIAS_NAME)

    query = Q('bool', filter=[
        Q('term', sensor_pk=sensor_pk),
        Q('terms', sequence=sequences),
        Q('term', type=record_type)
    ])

    ubb = ubq.query(query)
    ubb.script(source=f'ctx._source.sensor_pk = -{sensor_pk};')
    response = ubb.execute()
```

the response shows everything is okay but the sensor_pk doesn't get updated

`{'took': 165, 'timed_out': False, 'total': 502, 'updated': 5...}`

what might I be doing wrongly?

Comment: At first glance, everything seems to be correct. Can you call `_refresh` on your index? Maybe your refresh_interval is set to -1. I'm not sure though that your script content is correct, as you're using Python F-string but there's no `sensor_pk` in the Python context when you execute your code

Comment: the index is really small already. Doing so still doesn't seem to show any result.\

Comment: If the response shows that 502 documents have been updated, then they have been somehow, ES is not making it up :-) Can you show a document before and after the update?

Comment: I changed the way I was performing the update to use `update_by_query` instead. It now seems to work well. I've added an answer for the same. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the code to use `update_by_query`

```
def update_records(sequences, record_type, sensor_pk, es):
    if not sequences:
        return

    body = {
        "script": {
            "source": "ctx._source.sensor_pk = params.sensor_pk",
            "lang": "painless",
            "params": {
            "sensor_pk": f"-{sensor_pk}"
            }
        },
        "query": {
            "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {"term": {"sensor_pk": sensor_pk}},
                {"terms": {"sequence": list(set(sequences))}}
            ]
            }
        }
    }

    response = es.es.update_by_query(index=es.ALIAS_NAME, body=body)
```